# Function Notations for quadratics

Tags: functions, notation

Given $T(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$
Find $a,\,b$ and $c$ if $T(0) = -4$, $T(1) = -2$ and $T(2) = 6$

I first made $C$ for when $x = 0,\,-4$. But don't know were to go from here. 
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $c=-4$, it follows $T(1)=a+b-4$ and $T(2)=4a+2b-4$. Also, you know $T(1)=-2$ and $T(2)=6$. You must find $a$ and $b$ satisfying
\begin{align*}
a+b-4&=-2\\
4a+2b-4&=6
\end{align*}

Comment: So we just solve for a and b for both to work out the values? Do we make a = 0 and solve for b then?

Comment: We must solve the system of equations in order to obtain both $a$ and $b$.

Comment: So we solve the two equations you have at the bottom right? But how do we do this if we have two unknowns?

Comment: We must solve for $a$ in terms of $b$ the first equation, then plug this in the second equation:
From the first eq. $a=-2+4-b=2-b$
$\Longrightarrow\;4(2-b)+2b-4=6$ by second eq.

Comment: Yes i got it now!

Comment: So find b in the second equation and use that number to work out a when a = 2-b?

Comment: Yes, from this we have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $T(1) = a+b+c$, and $T(2) = 4a+2b+c$, but $c = T(0) = -4$. Can you finish it off...?